# What is the correct permission to read the rest of profile info?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

My app has permissions **User.ReadBasic.All**.
However, when I try to read person in same organization, I only can get name and address info.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/someone@example.com

{
   businessPhones: [],
   displayName: 'Jack Johns',
   givenName: 'Jack',
   id: '42d4f951-709d-4c13-81da-ab93afbdcda2'
   jobTitle: null, // <- here should have value
   mail: 'jack@example.com',
   mobilePhone: null, // <- here should have value
   officeLocation: null, // <- here should have value
   preferredLanguage: null, // <- here should have value
   surname: 'Johns',
   userPrincipalName: 'jack@example.com',
}
```

After reading [Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference), it seems I need **User.Read.All**, but it need admin permission.

However, when I use the token got from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)'s `tokenPlease()` in console. The GET can return all info correctly. Does that mean Graph Explorer gives me even admin permissions? If that, that is a security issue. (I am sure I am not admin in the organization)

What is the correct permission to read the rest of profile info without admin permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions. Please read what each of the permissions actually allows.  `User.ReadBasic.All`, as the name suggests, only provides reading a limited set of user profile properties.  All other properties are returned as null.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I just updated my question, please check again. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear.  User.ReadBasic.All is returning expected results.  User.Read.All will require admin consent - per design.  I can't see your Graph Explorer configuration, but it is possible that consent has been granted for User.Read.All or another more privileged permission that grants it the ability to read all users' full profiles.

Comment: Not my app, the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). But I think I get your points.

Comment: I don't have admin permission, but after signing in Graph Explorer, I have that admin permission. That means if someone uses `tokenPlease()` to get a token with admin permission in console, that might a security issue.

Comment: Hi Hongbo, the elevated permissions in the tokenPlease() token are limited by what your organization's tenant admin has granted. The default behavior (in which your tenant did not consent) would be the same as any other auth token you can acquire with your own app registration.